# Namecheap LiteSpeed Problem when Posting data from html form

Tags: post, namecheap, litespeed

I am facing a problem when trying to post data to my PHP from html form.
The issue is as follows:

1. When I submit less data like a 1 paragraph of Lorem Ipsum it works fine.
2. Submitting more paragraphs it fails instantly with error 403 Forbidden.
3. Tried solving using SecFilterScanPOST Off on .htaccess but to no avail.

[Error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJqdn.png)

Comment: `<IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecRuleEngine Off
   SecRequestBodyAccess Off
</IfModule>`   what about this ?

Answer (score 5):

To solve this error, @qtwrk's comment is correct that you must use the following code in your .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecRuleEngine Off
SecRequestBodyAccess Off
</IfModule>
```

WordPress running on Litespeed Server will often fail with a 403 error when you try to post any content while creating new pages and posts in WP Admin. This code solves that issue.

Answer (score 0):

> A solution about **disabling should help but it decreases security** — stops doing that.

**Better** to spend more time understanding the main reason and for example configure mod_security for Wordpress:

Based on [this article](https://www.ryanoun.com/notes/403-forbidden-errors-on-wordpress-apache-with-modsecurity/) you can disable some rules directly for `wp-admin` directory:

```xml
<LocationMatch "/wp-admin/">
  SecRuleRemoveById 300013
  SecRuleRemoveById 300014
  SecRuleRemoveById 300015
  SecRuleRemoveById 300016
  SecRuleRemoveById 300017
</LocationMatch>
```

Based on [this article](https://dipakgajjar.com/fix-403-forbidden-error-in-wordpress-modsecurity/) you can disable some rules directly for sub-directories:

```xml
<LocationMatch "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php">
  SecRuleRemoveById 300013
  SecRuleRemoveById 300015
  SecRuleRemoveById 300016
  SecRuleRemoveById 300017
  SecRuleRemoveById 949110
  SecRuleRemoveById 980130
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch "/wp-admin/page.php">
  SecRuleRemoveById 300013
  SecRuleRemoveById 300015
  SecRuleRemoveById 300016
  SecRuleRemoveById 300017
  SecRuleRemoveById 949110
  SecRuleRemoveById 980130
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch "/wp-admin/post.php">
  SecRuleRemoveById 300013
  SecRuleRemoveById 300015
  SecRuleRemoveById 300016
  SecRuleRemoveById 300017
  SecRuleRemoveById 949110
  SecRuleRemoveById 980130
</LocationMatch>
```

If you want to be sure that `mod_security` is used you can wrap the settings above in this:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  # ...
  # <LocationMatch ...>
  # ...
</IfModule>
```